# Is it worth using Redux with a Meteor / React app?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, redux

I've used Meteor a fair bit and love it, the publish/subscribe model, the way the whole framework is thought out, the ease of writing the server-side code...and I've used React with Meteor, and that's also cool.

However I've recently done a non-Meteor project in React/Redux and there's a lot to love about Redux. It's more effort to set up but the single point Store and all the associated tools/systems are very nice.

My web app will do a lot of database interaction and needs optimistic UI.

So I'm wondering whether to use Meteor/React/Redux for my next project, especially as there are some limitations in MiniMongo (e.g. no support for arrays). However I'm not finding a lot of relevant tutorials on how to hook them together, for example [this one](https://medium.com/front-end-developers/how-we-redux-part-1-introduction-18a24c3b7efe) is nearly 3 years old now. This makes me doubt whether many people are using this setup, and whether I'll be able to get it working easily:  I know from past experience that I need step by step tutorials to get past the initial hurdles with a new setup, then after that I can work things out for myself.

I'll use Meteor/Redux next for sure. I know them, I like them. The question is whether adding Redux is worth the overhead? I hope this is a suitable question for StackOverflow, if not I will try posting it elsewhere.

I'd like to hear reasons to use or not use Redux with Meteor/React, and any recommendations for tutorials. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think Redux is applicable in the non-meteor world, although there are alternatives now with graphql local state or the use of the React context api (which, thanks to React Hooks, is no longer deprecated)

Anyway, back to the story...

I have two separate Meteor apps, one that uses Redux, and the other that doesn't.

Redux works well with Meteor, it does the async thing quite well, but it adds a whole lot of complexity for arguable benefit. In a non-meteor app where you are doing much more in the way of orchestrating asynchronous API calls, then it makes total sense, because you can effectively decouple the data handling from the UI.

But in a typical Meteor app, use of publications and subscriptions means that the data flows naturally anyway. A UI button requests a back end action. The Meteor method does the work, and updates the database, and that data is updated in the UI automatically.

Let's take a scenario that I implemented recently. Members of my app need a Working With Children Check. They are issued a number, and when we are processing membershio renewals, we need to check that the number is still valid. This is initiated by a button on the UI, which calls a Meteor method, which in turn does an API call. The method simply updates the results of the check (even if it fails) into the member's database record. A return value from the Meteor call allows us to do a toast notificaton for the user, and pub/sub looks after updating the new status in the UI.

This could also be done with Redux, but pretty much all of the above code needs to be done anyway.

My preference is away from Redux, as there are alternatives, and it feels like it is a level of engineering that takes you away from writing your app.

Comment: Thanks! My issue is that I have large arrays that need individual cells to be updated, and it's tricky to make this reactive in MiniMongo.